# How to change root directory in htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm having this website that is bilingual, and I wanted to solve the problem by creating a `"/en"` subdirectory with all the pages inside it. 
I can get to the `example.com/en/page` URL, but I want to make the `example.com/en` the root directory so any redirect based on `"/another-page"` will go to `example.com/en/another-page,` instead of `example.com/another-page`

I tried using .htaccess with following commands :

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/en/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?localhost:8080\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /en/$1 [L]
```

But it didn't work. Any Ideas on how I can make this work?

Comment: "But it didn't work." - An error? Incorrect redirect? Nothing? Presumably you have a `RewriteEngine On` directive? Why the _condition_ that checks the `Host` header (this contradicts your `example.com`)? Anything else in your `.htaccess` file? Otherwise, what you have should already "work" (but can be simplified).

Comment: Yes I have RewriteEngine On.
It didn't do anything. After I added the .htaccess file, i clicked on an anchor tag with the url to /. I wanted it to go to example.com/en/ but it went to example.com
@MrWhite

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted in the question is a "rewrite", not a "redirect" - so that may be the underlying problem. If your application is getting the language from the `REQUEST_URI` then it won't see the rewritten URL containing the language.

Try the following at the top of your `.htaccess` in the root of the site:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule !^(en|xx)($|/) /en%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Where `xx` is the "other" language.

No need for the condition that checks against the `REQUEST_URI` server variable, as this should be checked in the `RewriteRule` *pattern* instead. And I've removed the check against `HTTP_HOST`, as that seems redundant in this particular example?

Comment: That didn't work either. What I'm trying to do is to check if the current page is in /en folder, basically if url is localhost:8080/en/something. If so, then to route all page redirects to the /en folder. For example if I'm on page localhost:8080/contact and pre anchor tag where href="/about", I want my website to go to localhost:8080/en/about not localhost:8080/about

Comment: You can't realistically check what the "current page" is _before_ the request you want to redirect. However, the above should redirect _everything_ - so it should do _something_? I've updated the regex to exclude the other language - presumably that is also expressed as a URL prefix?

Comment: So basically, I can't set my /en directory as a root from .htaccess?

Comment: Did the above "redirect" do _anything_? Did it redirect or not? You can inndeed effectively "hide" the subdirectory (which is what you are doing in the question) - but whether that works with your application is another matter. (You can't actually "change the document root" directory though - and neither do you want to.) As I asked in my initial comment... do you have any other directives in `.htaccess`? How are you routing your URLs? Or you are simply using physical HTML files?

Comment: TBH, I would have thought you should be redirecting this rather than rewriting anyway? Isn't `/en/` also accessible?